# Parity syncing in archive mode stuck at block 4839206

Tags: blockchain, parity, synchronization, docker, cloud-mining

I am running Parity inside docker in pod in Kubernets on Google Cloud.
The pod is using disk with 2700 GB for storing Ethereum blockchain, and currently
disk has about 2100 GB free.
Unfortunately for few days parity is stuck at block 4839206, it gives logs like this and block number in log does not change.

```
2019-04-20 17:05:15 UTC Syncing #4839206 0x5e68…aa34 0.00 blk/s 0.0 tx/s 0.0 
Mgas/s 0+ 0 Qed #28575 49/50 peers 206 KiB chain 4 KiB db 0 bytes queue 54 MiB 
sync RPC: 0 conn, 2 req/s, 32 µs
```

Arguments for docker image are:

```
    args: ["-d", "/ethereum-data", "--no-warp", "--tracing", "on", "--pruning", "archive","--jsonrpc-hosts", "all",
           "--jsonrpc-interface", "all", "--allow-ips=public", "--no-discovery"]
```

Have tried with adding maxpeers minpeers argument.

Have someone any ideas what can be the purpose of not syncing new blocks?